# If $\nabla\times\nabla\times\mathbf{F}$ = 0, then what can we conclude about $\nabla\times \mathbf{F} $, where $\mathbf{F}$ is a vector field?

Tags: mathematical-physics, vector-fields

If $\nabla\times\nabla\times \mathbf{F} = 0$, then can we say that $\nabla\times \mathbf{F} = 0$?

If yes, then how to prove it?

Comment: Your title and your text are NOT the same question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about pure [math.SE] with no physical context given. There are already plenty of general questions about the curl of a curl of a vector field on math.SE, e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1108020/143136, so migration does not seem useful.

Answer (score 2):

No, we can't say that $\nabla \times \textbf{F} = 0$.

As a counterexample, consider $\textbf{F} = x \hat{y} - y \hat{x}$.

Then, $\nabla \times \textbf{F} \neq 0$ (I will leave it for you to calculate its value), but you can easily verify that $\nabla \times \left(\nabla \times \textbf{F}\right) = 0$.

To answer the question in the title, there exists a scalar field $G$ such that $\nabla \times \textbf{F} = \nabla G$. (thanks to the comment by @Frobenius, I forgot to mention this initially)

Also, from [Stokes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem), we can conclude that the line integral of $\nabla \times \textbf{F}$ along any closed path is $0$.

Comment: $$
\mathrm{curl}\;\mathbf H\boldsymbol{=0}\:\:\boldsymbol{\Longleftrightarrow}\:\:\mathbf H\boldsymbol{=}\mathrm{grad\; G}
$$
that is
$$
\boldsymbol{\nabla\times}\mathbf H\boldsymbol{=0}\:\:\boldsymbol{\Longleftrightarrow}\:\:\mathbf H\boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{\nabla} \mathrm G
$$